# React child component render error

Tags: javascript, debugging, reactjs, parent-child

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Tabs from './TabParent.jsx';

var Topbar = React.createClass ({
    propTypes : {
        tbOptionsMenu : React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        lftSideEle : React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        typeOfTransaction : React.PropTypes.number,
        tabAttr : React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
    },

    getDefaultProps : function () {
        return ({
            tabAttr : [
                {
                    tabClassName : 'tabPreview tab',
                    tabName : 'Preview'
                },
                {
                    tabClassName : 'tabBody tab',
                    tabName : 'Body'
                },
                {
                    tabClassName : 'tabSleeve tab',
                    tabName : 'Sleeve'
                }
            ]
        });
    },

    render : function () {
        var tbOptionsMenu = (
            <div id="tbOptionsMenu" className="tbIcon" data-action="menuItem-main" data-tooltip="MENU : Why not take a peek, for you may find what you seek...">i</div>
        );

        var lftSideEle = (
            <div className="tbDetails tbBrandParent">
                <div className="mainHeading tbBrandName" data-tooltip="Your Brand Name" data-action="labelmenu-open">Brand Name</div>
                <div className="mainHeading tbDesignName" data-tooltip="Your Design Name">a new design</div>
            </div>
        );

        return (
            <div className='topBar'>
                {this.props.tbOptionsMenu && tbOptionsMenu}
                {this.props.lftSideEle && lftSideEle}
                <Tabs {this.props.tabAttr}> </Tabs>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default Topbar;
```

Webpack reports an error on render of the component 'Tabs'.Error is the unhelpful: 'Module build failed: SyntaxError: .... unexpected token at line...'

Omitting the line, the rest of the code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to

```
<Tabs tabAttr={this.props.tabAttr} />
```

instead of

```
<Tabs {this.props.tabAttr}> </Tabs>
```

You can read more about this here
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Answer (score 1):

You should add attribute name

```
<Tabs tabAttr={this.props.tabAttr} />
```

or if you want pass all props from parent to child you can use [spread attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html) like this

```
<Tabs {...this.props} />
```

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you for the solution along with the spread attr suggestion. Meeh was a few seconds earlier so I hope its ok if I give him the tick.